# VersionConflict six 1.5.2 vs. six>=1.6.0' when trying to pip install pystan

Tags: python, pip

I get the following error on installing pystan.

```sh
$ pip install pystan
```

I have ubuntu 14.04 and python 2.7 
I have tried few of the mentioned solutions on other similar threads but all of them eventually come down to error code 1 error.

```
Downloading/unpacking pystan
  Downloading pystan-2.15.0.0.tar.gz (25.4MB): 25.4MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_ali/pystan/setup.py) egg_info for package pystan
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_ali/pystan/setup.py", line 239, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip_build_ali/pystan/setup.py", line 211, in setup_package
        dist = setup(**metadata)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 321, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 389, in finalize_options
        ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2324, in require
        items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 859, in resolve
        raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (six 1.5.2 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('six>=1.6.0'))
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_ali/pystan/setup.py", line 239, in <module>

    setup_package()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_ali/pystan/setup.py", line 211, in setup_package

    dist = setup(**metadata)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 321, in __init__

    _Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__

    self.finalize_options()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 389, in finalize_options

    ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2324, in require

    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 859, in resolve

    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)

pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (six 1.5.2 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('six>=1.6.0'))

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ali/pystan
Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpXPB8XS
```

Any thoughts what might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (six 1.5.2 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('six>=1.6.0'))
```

It's saying that the required `six` package is outdated, you will need to upgrade it before installing your library.

```
pip install --upgrade six
```